# Creating Objects via "each" and automatically name them

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, each

I'm trying to "read" dom-elements, and then to store some of their values in Objects.
It's bascially working, but I'm wondering how to name them properly (according to their index for instance). I'd love to have something like "element0.string", "element1.string" etc. Whats the right approach in your opinion?

```
function Element(index, el, height, string) {

    this.el = el;
    this.height = height;
    this.string = string;
    this.index = index;

    }

$(".element").each(function(){

    var el = $(this);
    var height = $(this).height();
    var index = $(this).index();
    var string = "Foobar";

    element = new Element(index, el, height, string);       

    });

alert(element.index);
```

Comment: you can use some array and a counter, var myarrays = []; , myarrays[ 0 ] = "random value";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use the index parameter that comes with the `each` method:

```
$('.element').each(function(i) {
    // your code
    window['element'+i] = new Element( /* etc. */ );
});
```

Basically you're using the index parameter in conjunction with a concatenated variable name. Since global variables usually belong to the `window` object, you can access the `window` object directly and add a property (i.e. your global variable) to it.

### Edit

As the commenter below said, the best way might be to throw all your newly created objects into an array:

```
var elements = [];

// your code
    elements.push(new Element());
```

This will let you access each new object like this:

```
elements[0]; // => your first element
```

This is a more common way, and seems a little bit more modular and clean.

Comment: I'd honestly opt for an array rather than attaching it globally to the `window`, but in context of how to create individual names for each iteration, this is the best way (least amount of extra code required).

Comment: "window["foo"+bar]" was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for that mate. In this case I will go with the array, even better. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

you have the elem and the index inside each function

refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

you should use in this way

```
$(".element").each(function(index,elem){


    var height = $(elem).height();

    var string = "Foobar";

    element = new Element(index, $(elem), height, string);       

    });
```